Unit Root tests for Timeseries Analysis - Derivation of the Characteristic Equation
The below equation describes a timeseries process.
$${\displaystyle y_{t}=a_{1}y_{t-1}+a_{2}y_{t-2}+\cdots +a_{p}y_{t-p}+\varepsilon _{t}}$$
To determine whether this process contains a Unit Root, we solve the Characteristic Equation.
To write down the Characteristic Equation, we swap symbols $y_{t-n}$ for expressions in terms of the lag operator such that $y_{t-n}=L^ny_t$, and remove the term $\varepsilon_t$.
$${\displaystyle y_{t}=a_{1}Ly_{t}+a_{2}L^2y_{t}+\cdots +a_{p}L^py_{t}}$$
This is equivalent to
$${\displaystyle y_{t}-a_{1}Ly_{t}-a_{2}L^2y_{t}-\cdots -a_{p}L^py_{t}}=0.$$
We then factor out $y_t$, and solve for $L$
$${\displaystyle 1-a_{1}L-a_{2}L^2-\cdots -a_{p}L^p}=0.$$
My question is why? I am searching for a more detailed proof of explanation as to why we take these steps.
There are a few things here which I think are a bit strange. $L$ is an operator, so to separate it from $y_t$ doesn't make much sense.
Specifically, I don't take issue with the fact that $L$ can be factored into parenthesys like this
$${\displaystyle (1-a_{1}L-a_{2}L^2-\cdots -a_{p}L^p})y_t=0$$
however, to then interpret the operator $L$ as a variable and solve for $L$ seems disturbing.

Hi: You're not solving for $L$. It's fixed. You solve for the $a_i$. They are the roots of the characteristic equation associated with the AR(p). Note that the reason you can treat $L$ as a variable in the algebraic machinery has to do with operator theory and is discussed in functional analysis. That's definitely not an area that I can give any help with but hopefully this helps some.

@mlofton Thanks for your feedback, but I'm not sure that makes any sense. Is it not the case that the $a_i$ terms can all be different? $a_1\ne a_2$ for example. Since we have one equation (one constraint) we cannot solve for $p$ variables $a_i$.

Maybe I'm being stupid here. Possibly a better question is how can we solve the equation for the $a_i$: $1-a_1x-a_2 x^2-\cdots -a_p x^p = 0$

For a p order polynomial with distinct roots, there's a theorem that says there are $p$ of them. But I don't know the exact method. It's probably in a theoretical differential equations text. Most of the time, the roots are found in the code from the corresponding software package so the details will be in the function itself. For example, R has the function which I think is called polyroot. For example,  if you use R, you can look at the source for that. It should be part of the base package but it's probably not easy. R-core members wrote most of base and they don't write trivial code.

The duplicate answers your final question (about the algebraic rules of working with an operator like $L$).  BTW, one doesn't solve a polynomial for its coefficients $a_i$!  Those coefficients are given: they determine the process.  By definition, a root is a value $x$ for which the polynomial equals zero.

The equation actually factors into $p$ terms. Let me send you a link that I found recently that goes into some algebraic details regarding the AR(p). it doesn't provide the details for solving the characteristic equation it but it does provide more than the standard background. I have to find it so it may take me a few minutes.

I defer to whuber for the details but this link should give you a pretty idea. whuber: my $a_i$ were meant to be the $\phi_{i}$ but I could have messed things up. http://econweb.umd.edu/~chao/Teaching/Econ624/Econ624_Lecture_on_Autoregression.pdf What user3728501 is interested in starts in the page 20's but I would read the whole thing from the beginning.

@mlofton The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra asserts such polynomials completely factor into exactly $p$ terms (counted with appropriate multiplicity) provided the coefficients are considered to be complex numbers.  An extension of that theorem for real coefficients asserts all such polynomials factor as products of linear and irreducible quadratic terms (the roots of the latter are complex conjugates and not purely real).

Thanks whuber: What area of math does this fall under ? I've read analysis texts and even attempted functional analysis texts, Yet, I never come away feeling confident about the material.

@whuber  I never saw the shift operator explained like that before ( in the duplicate). That was a really nice explanation. Thanks. Still, if you can let me know what area of math the whole concept of characteristic equations, being inside the unit circle, fundamental theorem of algebra etc falls under, it's appreciated.

@mlofton The FTA is algebra--it's taught routinely in high schools, without proof, and usually proven in undergraduate courses.  (There are many proofs, of which one nice one is an application of Complex Analysis.)  The shift operator is part of Functional Analysis, which is a more advanced topic--but my understanding is that some introductory undergraduate math texts are now introducing and building on such concepts.  Characteristic equations show up in studies of the properties of differential and difference equations as well as being basic to linear algebra.

Thanks for direction. I'll have a greater chance now of finding stuff the next time I do one of my "understanding the characteristic equation in the AR(p)" journeys. I've done many with not much bang for the buck.

@mlofton The characteristic equation is identical to the characteristic polynomial of an appropriate linear operator: that's the connection with linear algebra.

whuber: okay thanks. I'm providing this link because, at a glance, it looks even better than the link I pointed to earlier. I've done many, many, many google searches over the years and somehow this document never came up before. ( This time I used the term "characteristic equation" in my search  which I don't remember using in the past ).  I'm really looking forward to going through it. Thanks for your great help. https://econweb.ucsd.edu/muendler/teach/gen/diffeqn.pdf

@mlofton That monograph reads well.  Chapter 5 explains how the characteristic equation arises and its connection with the familiar characteristic polynomial of square matrices.  I recommend starting with the final paragraph in the entire document because it summarizes the key ideas.

whuber: glad to hear it. I haven't had a chance to read it yet but I glanced and it looked useful. One of us is very good at math and one isn't, and the one who's not tends to like read these things from the beginning and sloooooooooowly. Thanks again.
